# How to get parameter names in python format function?

Tags: python-3.x, string, templates

```
func = "Hello {name}. how are you doing {time}!".format
```

For example, let's assume `func` is defined as above.

we don't have a definition of `func` at hand but we have an instance of it.
how can I get all arguments to this function?

apparently `inspect.getargspec(func)` does not work here!

if I just run this with empty parameters it returns an error with one missing parameter at a time, but I don't know how to get them directly:

```
a()
-------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-228-8d7b4527e81d> in <module>
----> 1 a()

KeyError: 'name'
```

Comment: If it's parsing the string then doing dynamic checking at runtime, I wouldn't think that that information would be a part of the function itself. It wouldn't know that a `name` "parameter" exists until it goes over the string and finds it, and that wouldn't happen until `.format` is called.

Comment: You can parse the template string with `string` module, but not from the `str.format` instance

Answer (score 0):

what exactly are you trying to do? what is your expected output? as far as i know, there is no possibility to insert name and time, after you define func. because `"string".format("call variables") <----` it cant call variables that are not defined. As far as i know the calling process happens first, independent of the formatting type. (f string, %, .format().. whatever you use)